# Is this a right question? "Who did had a problem last night?"

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

Is this a right question?

> Who did had a problem last night?

Comment: No. "Did had" makes no sense. Use one verb or the other, not both.

Comment: Maybe something like "Did anyone have a problem last night?"

Comment: Who has, who had= present and past tense; who **did have (emphatic past tense)**.

Comment: Hi there. Asking for text to be checked is off-topic.

Comment: Possibly "who did have a problem" would work.

Comment: Welcome! To turn this into an on-topic question, please use the "Edit" link below the question to say more about what part of the sentence you're concerned with, and what meaning it should have.

Comment: **Who HAD a problem last night?** The pronoun Who" is the subject (Marina had a problem last night) and also a question word, and therefore doesn't need an auxiliary to form the interrogative.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Did had" makes no sense. Use one verb or the other:

> Who did a problem last night?

> Who had a problem last night?

The pronoun Who" is the subject (Marina had a problem last night) and also a question word, and therefore doesn't need an auxiliary to form the interrogative.

Maybe you mean something like "Did anyone have a problem last night?"

In an emphatic past tense, the question

> Who did have a problem last night?

Would be grammatically correct, but it has a particular emphatic meaning